# Using Dijkstra's algorithm with an unordered_map graph

Tags: c++, algorithm, dictionary, graph, dijkstra

So this my current code, I will post the header declarations below...

```
// Using Dijkstra's
int Graph::closeness(string v1, string v2){
int edgesTaken = 0;
unordered_map<string, bool> visited;
unordered_map<string, int> distances;
string source = v1; // Starting node
while(source != v2 && !visited[source]){
    // The node has been visited
    visited[source] = 1;
    // Set all initial distances to infinity
    for(auto i = vertices.begin(); i != vertices.end(); i++){
        distances[i->first] = INT_MAX;
    }
    // Consider all neighbors and calculate distances from the current node
    // & store them in the distances map
    for(int i = 0; i < vertices[source].edges.size(); i++){
        string neighbor = vertices[source].edges[i].name;           
        distances[neighbor] = vertices[source].edges[i].weight; 
    }   
    // Find the neighbor with the least distance
    int minDistance = INT_MAX;
    string nodeWithMin;
    for(auto i = distances.begin(); i != distances.end(); i++){
        int currDistance = i->second;
        if(currDistance < minDistance){
            minDistance = currDistance;
            nodeWithMin = i->first;
        }       
    }
    // There are no neighbors and the node hasn't been found yet
    // then terminate the function and return -1. The nodes aren't connected
    if(minDistance == INT_MAX) 
        return -1;
    // Set source to the neighbor that has the shortest distance
    source = nodeWithMin;
    // Increment edgesTaken
    edgesTaken++;
    // clear the distances map to prepare for the next iteration
    distances.clear();
}
return edgesTaken;
}
```

Declarations (This is an undirected graph) :

```
class Graph{
    private:
            // This holds the connected name and the corresponding we
            struct EdgeInfo{
                    std::string name;
                    int weight;
                    EdgeInfo() { }
                    EdgeInfo(std::string n, int w) : name(n), weight(
            };

            // This will hold the data members of the vertices, inclu
            struct VertexInfo{
                    float value;
                    std::vector<EdgeInfo> edges;
                    VertexInfo() { }
                    VertexInfo(float v) : value(v) { }
            };

            // A map is used so that the name is used as the index
            std::unordered_map<std::string, VertexInfo> vertices;
```

**NOTE: Please do not suggest that I change the header declarations, I am contributing to a project that has already had 8 other functions written and it's definitely too late to go back and change anything since every other function would then have to be rewritten** 
I'm currently getting incorrect output.  The function is handling a 0 distance situation correctly however (If two vertices aren't connected then the function should return a -1).  If the two nodes are the same vertex ex closeness("Boston", "Boston") then the function should return a 0.

**Example graph** 
[image: Example Graph]

the closeness of the following two vertices on the left will be on the right:

```
Correct:
Trenton -> Philadelphia: 2
Binghamton -> San Francisco: -1
Boston -> Boston: 0
Palo Alto -> Boston: -1

Output of my function:
Trenton -> Philadelphia: 3
Binghamton -> San Francisco: -1
Boston -> Boston: 0
Palo Alto -> Boston: 3
```

I've tried to copy dijkstra's exactly how it is described, but I'm getting incorrect readings, I've been trying to figure this out for a while now -> Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: For me Trenton - > Philadelphia  is really 3 edges long because  3+2+10 < 3+18.

Comment: There are a number of issues.  First, your algorithm isn't really keeping track of all of the reachable nodes, so it simply moves along the shortest path from any given node, without regards to the total path length.  Second, The return is returning the total distance, but your 'correct' results above is the total number of vertices in the path.  Which do you want?

Comment: I've edited my code. The algorithm needs to output the minimum # edges taken to get from vertex v1 to vertex v2.  As you can see in the graph @Johan there are only 2 jumps needed to get from Trenton -> Philidelphia

Comment: Have you tried printing out a list of each node's neighbours to ensure that data is correct?

Comment: Yes but your edges are weighted and you actually use this weight to compute the shortest path...

Comment: @Johan I'll clarify this with my prof....fairly certain she wants my function to find the minimum number of edges taken to get to vertex2 rather than the shortest path via the total weight.

Comment: So I'm assuming I'm going to have to create a set of paths with their associated edgesTaken, search through the set for the path with the least edgesTaken and output that number....The question is: How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your implementation is wrong, and it is only by chance you get "correct" results.

Lets do one example by hand. From Trenton to Philadelphia. I use the first letter of the cities as labels.

```
First iteration
visited = [(T, 1), (N, 0), (W, 0), (P, 0), (B, 0)]
minDistance = 3;
nodeWithMin = N;
edgesTaken = 1

second iteration
visited = [(T, 1), (N, 1), (W, 0), (P, 0), (B, 0)]
minDistance = 2;
nodeWithMin = W;
edgesTaken = 2

third iteration
visited = [(T, 1), (N, 1), (W, 1), (P, 0), (B, 0)]
minDistance = 2;
nodeWithMin = N;
edgesTaken = 3;

fourth iteration
N is already 1 so we stop. Can you see the errors?
```

Traditionally Dijkstras shortest path algorithm is implemented with a priority queue

```
dijkstra(graph, source)
    weights is a map indexed by nodes with all weights = infinity
    predecessor is a map indexed by nodes with all predecessors set to itself
    unvisited is a priority queue containing all nodes

    weights[source] = 0
    unvisited.increase(source)

    while unvisited is not empty
      current = unvisited.pop();
      for each neighbour to current
        if weights[current] + edge_weight(current, neighbour) < weights[neighbour]
          weights[neighbour] = weights[current] + + edge_weight(current, neighbour)
          unvisited.increase(neighbour)
          predecessors[neighbour] = current

    return (weights, predecessors)
```

And you can get the path length by following the predecessors.

Comment: This is a much better clarification than the one my instructor provided for how Dijkstra's works...Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is most certainly not a real answer to the question (since I'm not pointing you in a direction regarding *your* implementation), but did you think about just using the Boost Graph library?

It boils down to writing a short Traits class for your graph structure (and thus it is not necessary to alter your graph definition/header) and is - at least for these fundamental algorithms - proven to be working stable and correctly.

I'd always suggest not to reinvent the wheel especially when it comes to graphs and numerics...

Comment: 1: What is useful to me in the Boost Graph library in this situation
2: What would be the members of the Traits class?

Comment: 1. I've looked a bit deeper into the concepts need for the Dijktstra algorithm in Boost Graph and in this situation if you're not going to implement any other algorithms on your graph structure you're maybe better off fixing your own code and look out for nasty special cases. If you anticipate hacking a lot of graph algorithms for this structure in the near future it is generally worthwhile looking into Boost Graph. 2. The Traits class would define your vertex and edge types (the latter is the reason for my answer to 1.), iterator on them as well as access functions for these iterators.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with Palo Alto -> Boston seems to be that the algorithm takes the route `Palo Alto -> San Fransisco -> Los Angeles -> San Fransisco` (edgesTaken = 3) and then fails the while condition because San Fransisco's been visited already.

Comment: Right....do you have an idea how I can handle disconnected vertices better than the way my code is currently handling it?

Comment: Off the top of my head: use a bool (`bFound` or whatever, initialised to false) that you can set to true when source == v2. Check that value after you've exited the loop: `if(!bFound) return -1;`